# Postgres search IPAddress(inet) :How to search the matching ip by input part of the ip ？

Tags: postgresql, inet

[image: DB Data]

Input:"a000:0"
Require Result： 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,13,14 as the result.

Comment: you can use like operator after casting to text, like `select ip from t where ip::text like '%a000:0%'`

Comment: How to insert a inet data into DB table?

Comment: same as everything else

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: select ip from t where ip::text like '%a000:0%'. This SQL just seach the ip like 'a000:0'. I want the 'a000::','a000:1','a000:11','a000:111'  as the result.